# Weird problem with a simple redirect command

Tags: redirect, terminal, find

Having a wierd problem with a simple command that refuses to work -
I am trying to run a 'find' command and redirect the output to a file

The find writes the results to the screen, but the redirect never creates the file.

FYI- Running Ubuntu 19.10, bash shell

I've tried about a half dozen different permutations of this command, nothing works.

```
find / -name caffeine >> xxx
find / -name caffeine -print >> xxx
find / -name "caffeine" -print >> xxx
find / -name "caffeine" {} \; >> xxx   
This gives an error "find: paths must precede expression: `{}'"

none of these ever creates the file xxx
```

Help!

Answer (score 0):

">>" is mostly used to append to the existing file. Usually, if you are redirecting the entire output to some file ">" should do the job.

For example:

If you are trying to find the file ending in .txt in your current directory and redirect the output to the new file. Following code should work:

```
find . -name "*.txt" > filename
```

```
.       : Specifies that the directory you are looking for is the current 
          directory.
-name   : Looking for the file with matching name
"*.txt" : Finds all the files ending with .txt extension
>       : Redirection to a file
```

I hope that helps. If you are more specific as to what you want. I may help you more.

Comment: ```I've never had a need to overwrite a file with a redirect, so I am accustomed to using >>

I found the syntax that works for this use;
find / -name caffeine >> xxx

This redirects ONLY stdout to the file xxx (appending)```